# Is there an easier way to turn Canvas locations into Node2D locations

Tags: godot

Ok, so I have a node tree in my main scene that is like this (simplified)

```
root
|- LevelHolder
|- Player
|- Camera2D
|- CanvasLayer
  |- SomeUI
    |- ...
  |- Extents
    |- TopLeft
    |- BottomRight
```

And the situation I have is that my Canvas Layer has a full rect layout to stretch across the screen, and then my SomeUI element contains a bunch of UI elements that make up a HUD and a frame. I've got a Camera2D that allows me to zoom in and out on my player and level, so the editor's placement of the Node2D elements doesn't match the in-game view, since the Camera moves and zooms.

I don't want my player to be able to move underneath my HUD elements, so I've got these Extents objects in the CanvasLayer, which I can anchor to the top-left and bottom-right corners of the part of my HUD that I actually want the player to be able to walk around in.

So what I think I need to do is turn Canvas positions into positions I can set for my player.

After a lot of trial and error, this is what worked for me:

```
var tl = $CanvasLayer/Extents/TopLeft
var tlgp = tl.get_viewport_transform() * tl.get_global_transform()
$Player.topleft = self.get_viewport_transform().affine_inverse().xform(tlgp.origin)

var br = $CanvasLayer/Extents/BottomRight
var brgp = br.get_viewport_transform() * br.get_global_transform()
$Player.bottomright = self.get_viewport_transform().affine_inverse().xform(brgp.origin)
```

Which works, but seems like a lot of work, and it took me a lot of screwing around to find this all. And I can leave out `self.get_global_transform()` in this case because I know that `root`'s global transform is the identity, but in general it'd be even more complicated.

So, my real question is have I just overcomplicated this? Is there some method I could use that would just do all of this for me (or something else entirely) that would let me easily place a Node2D underneath a Canvas element, no matter what size the window is, or how it's stretched or squashed?

Answer (score 0):

**What you are doing is correct.**

Is it overkill? Perhaps. Assuming the UI does not change in way that the extends need to move, you could have the screen coordinates computed beforehand… Or compute them only when necessary.

Another thing to consider is how you are moving the `Camera2D`. If the camera is following the player, you can use "drag margins" that you use to specify how close the the border of the screen it has to get before the view begins to move. *Although that might not be viable depending on the game.*

And for another alternative, you could put the game world in a `Viewport`, and perhaps use a `ViewportContainer` which will be part of the UI. *Although `Viewport`s are a performance consideration - in particular for mobile - chances are you can afford this solution. This approach also allows to have a different resolution for the game world and the UI. See also [How to make a silky smooth camera for pixelart games in Godot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxVQsi9wnw8)*

*This rest of this answer is confirmation of what you are doing, and hopefully making it easier to understand.*

---

The official documentation has a formula for the screen position:

```
var screen_coord = get_viewport_transform() * (get_global_transform() * local_pos)
```

*See [Viewport and canvas transforms](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/2d/2d_transforms.html).*

First of all, we don't need to use `get_global_transform()` since we have property for it:

```
var screen_coord = get_viewport_transform() * (global_transform * local_pos)
```

---

If we know we are dealing with a `Control` and we want its position (i.e. `Vector2.ZERO` in local space) we can write a shorter version:

```
var screen_coord = get_viewport_transform() * rect_global_position
```

---

On the other hand, for a `Node2D` (and again we want its position) we can do this:

```
var screen_coord = get_viewport_transform() * global_position
```

Which is the same as:

```
var screen_coord = get_viewport_transform() * global_transform.origin
```

By the way, you get the same result like this (Which is what you are doing):

```
var screen_coord = (get_viewport_transform() * global_transform).origin
```

The difference is that here we are composing the transformation, which is extra work.

---

However, since we want to place a `Node2D` in the screen coordinates of something else, we need the inverse process.

Given this equation:

```
screen_coord = get_viewport_transform() * global_position
```

We can compose the inverse of one of these transforms at the start of both sides, like this:

```
get_viewport_transform().affine_inverse() * screen_coord
=
get_viewport_transform().affine_inverse() * get_viewport_transform() * global_position
```

And - of course - `get_viewport_transform().affine_inverse() * get_viewport_transform()` cancels out (to an identity transform, which we can omit), so we have:

```
get_viewport_transform().affine_inverse() * screen_coord = global_position
```

Flip it, and you have the means to position the `Node2D` at a given screen position:

```
global_position = get_viewport_transform().affine_inverse() * screen_coord
```

---

Now we can combine the computation of the screen position and how we position a `Node2D` at a given screen position. For example:

```
var screen_coords := control.get_viewport_transform() * control.rect_global_position
node2D.global_position = node2D.get_viewport_transform().affine_inverse() * screen_coords
```

*You can use `xform` instead of `*` if you prefer. However, be aware that `xform` returns Variant, so you lose type information.*

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the answer. Your final version does look a bit more approachable, but mostly it's good to know I wasn't just crazy and making things up.

I was actually considering making a viewport that was just the camera and then layering the view into the UI, but that seemed a bit overkill, so it's good to know I'm not crazy there either!